# Does it matter for SEO that my sites uses http 302 instead of 301 for redirects

Tags: redirects

Just found out that my administrator has set all redirects to temporary 302 instead of 301

i.e main site http://example.com and http://example2.com redirects to http://example.com/example2 but  from wget I can see using 302 not 301

Comment: Are they temporary or permanent redirects?

Comment: They are permanent, but now that someone has modified the urls its confusing because there is not an old and new site, its just that one site is named after the company, and then I have multiple urls for each product and those urls redirect to different locations on the company site.

Comment: They might not be explicitly serving a 302, but a redirect will generally _default_ to a 302 (however they are doing it) - so it might be an honest mistake on their part. (?!)

Comment: sure, certinaly nothing dishonest on their part - they have now all been changed to 301s :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the redirects are temporal, this is fine. If the old domain should be disregarded and the new domain should be used, this is bad.

As long as there's 302, the bots will periodically check the first domain and keep those in the results. If you 301 them, you tell them "forgot old url, only use new url". This last part is not happening now.

Comment: They are permanent, but now that someone has modified the urls in my original question its confusing because there is not an old and new site, its just that one site is named after the company, and then I have multiple urls for each product and those urls redirect to different locations on the company site.